# ones complement of 0 - 0

Tags: c, ip, checksum, integer-arithmetic, ones-complement

For background,  I'm trying to calculate a checksum for an IP packet which is stored in constant memory (can't modify it in place).   Before doing the checksum, I'm supposed to pretend the existing checksum in the packet is 0.   Rather than copy all the data to temporary buffer, and store 0, I'd like to do a checksum of the entire packet, and then subtract the existing checksum from the result.

To do this, I was looking for a one's complement version of subtraction which I found [here](https://courses.cs.vt.edu/csonline/NumberSystems/Lessons/SubtractionWithOnesComplement/index.html).  Unfortunately, if I use this, and subtract 0 from 0, I get 0x1111 instead of the expected 0:

1. Convert 0 to one's complement:  [1111]
2. Next, we add 0:   [1111]
3. no overflow bit, so we're done...

I would have expected 0 - 0 to be 0 -- what am I missing?

Comment: There are two representations of 0 in ones complement: +0 (0000) and -0 (1111).

Comment: What does one's complement buy you?

Comment: Instead of copying the entire buffer, you could save the current checksum, set it to 0, calculate the checksum, then put the original back in, assuming you don't want to use the new checksum you calculated.

Comment: @n.m.  The checksum in an IPv4 header is calculated that way: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_header_checksum

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, this is a concurrent system, and my code should technically not have write access to that part of memory.   I can do a ones compliment before and after the checksum, but that means I can't use acceleration as effectively.

Comment: @PaulR  Note: C does not require ones complement to have 2 zeros. the "-0" can be a is a trap representation or a normal value.  Certainly a 2's complement emulation of 1`s complete will have 2 "zeros".

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to subtract.

If the checksum is valid, calculating the checksum over the entire packet, including the checksum, should give you 0.  If the result is not 0, the packet is corrupted.

This is how routers validate the checksum.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to Read this tutorial on One's Complement

https://courses.cs.vt.edu/csonline/NumberSystems/Lessons/SubtractionWithOnesComplement/index.html

I think this is easy:

```
0000 - 0000 = 0000 + 1111 = 1111
```

As the last `1111` is in One's Complement form, we know that this is a Negative Number for having a Leading `1`.
The Last Operation is One's Complement (`1111`).

Final Answer is `- 0000`.
As you know a Cons of One's Complement Calculation is that having two form for
presenting Zero `0`.